# CSS works but SASS can't change style of component

Tags: css, sass, vuetify.js

I'm trying to override min-height property of a class named application--wrap but the code only works when declared into CSS style:

Code that works:

```
<style lang="css" scoped>
  .application--wrap{
    min-height: 0px;
  }
</style>
```

Code that doesn't works:

```
<style lang="sass" scoped>
    .application--wrap
        min-height: 0px;
</style>
```

"Full" code:

```
              <v-app>
                <div class="container-fluid centerTable">
                  <v-data-table
                    v-bind:headers="headers"
                    :items="listLayers"
                    :rows-per-page-items= "[5, 10]"
                    :custom-sort="customSort"
                    :loading="loading"
                    v-bind:pagination.sync="pagination"
                    class="elevation-1 layersTable"
                  >
              </v-app>
```

The class that i'm trying to override it's created on render by the Vuetify.

Comment: Did you install sass? Sass must be installed, usually via a package manager like NPM or Homebrew

Comment: Yes, and sass works in other classes. Only on this class (created on render by Vuetify) the code doesn't work.

Comment: The `lang` attribute describes the *human readable* language (such as `en-us` for American English) the element contains. It doesn't make sense to use it on a `style` element.

Comment: You're wrong, the lang attribute in this case is a pre processor: https://vue-loader-v14.vuejs.org/pt_BR/configurations/pre-processors.html

Comment: Not sure if this is the case, but you are using SASS syntax here, when the loader actually uses SCSS syntax.

Comment: Sadly, not the case :(

Comment: Can you also add the html and vue component? So that we can get a better view on what you try to achieve.

Comment: How are you using to build your VueJS app? You might have to make adjustments to your `sass-loader` as stated here to use SASS: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sass-vs-scss

Comment: There isn't nothing wrong with the sass-loader, it works with other components (like bootstrap components). I can't add too much code because the code isn't mine, it's from the local where i work.